# How do I access a new cell created by Cell(i,j).Split in Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint, cell

Assume I have a table in Powerpoint which looks the left table in this illustration. Straight forward, two columns, two rows.

```
  ___________________                    ___________________ 
 |         |         |                  |         |         |
 |  1,1    |  1,2    |    Split         |  1,1    |  1,2    |
 |         |         |                  |         |         |
 |_________|_________|    ----->        |_________|_________|
 |         |         |    ----->        |         |   ?,?   |
 |  2,1    |  2,2    |                  |  2,1    |_________|
 |         |         |                  |         |   ?,?   |
 |_________|_________|                  |_________|_________|
```

I have access to the shape holding the table via the following variable

```
dim myShape As PowerPoint.Shape
```

I can access the lower right cell using (remember that VBA cells are 1-based, not zero-based)

```
myShape.Table.Cell(2,2)
```

I can split any cell. Let's split the lower right cell into 2 rows:

```
myShape.Table.Cell(2,2).Split 2,1
```

my table now looks like the right one of the two tables at the top.

How would I access any of the two cells in the lower right corner, indicated by `?,?`?

I have tried

```
myShape.Table.Cell(2,2).Shape.Table.Cell(1,1)
```

for example, to access the upper of these two cells. I have also inspected the respective vba-objects in the vba debugger and did some google research. All I was able to find was how to split cells, not how to access any cells after splitting. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you split a cell, PowerPoint thinks there are more rows (or columns, if you split that way). The first statement would access the top cell of the split, the second statement the lower one:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Table.Cell(Row:=2, Column:=2).Select
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Table.Cell(Row:=3, Column:=2).Select
```